# Getting two Java Swing Forms to communicate with one another

Tags: java, swing

Hi I have two Swing forms...InputStudentInfo and InputStudentAddressInfo. InputStudentInfo has a simple text field that allows the user to enter a student's name. It also has a button labeled "Add address" that when clicked, opens up InputStudentAddressInfo. This form has a text field that allows the user to enter the students address. It too has a save button. My issue is I need to pass the value entered for the students address to InputStudentInfo when the user clicks on the save address button.  This is the code for InputStudentInfo:

```
 /*
  * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
    Properties.
  * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */

 package testswing;

 public class InputStudentInfo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 /**
 * Creates new form InputStudentInfo
 */
 public InputStudentInfo() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    nameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    addAddress = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Name");

    saveButton.setText("Save");
    saveButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            saveButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    addAddress.setText("Add Address");
    addAddress.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addAddressActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new 
    javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(

    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(70, 70, 70)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(56, 56, 56)

            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
             (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)

            .addComponent(addAddress)

            .addComponent(saveButton)
            .addComponent(nameField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 
             93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(154, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(60, 60, 60)
   .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
   (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(nameField, 
    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 
    javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
    javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(39, 39, 39)
            .addComponent(addAddress)
     .addPreferredGap
     (javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 78, 
     Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(saveButton)
            .addGap(57, 57, 57))
    );

    pack();

  }// </editor-fold>   
   // end of generated code     

   StudentDataModel studentdatamodel = new StudentDataModel();

   private void addAddressActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    // TODO add your handling code here:
    InputStudentAddressInfo addStudentAddressForm = new 

    InputStudentAddressInfo(studentdatamodel);

    addStudentAddressForm.setSize(800,600);

    addStudentAddressForm.setVisible(true);
}                                          

private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    // Create a Student 

        Student newStudent = new Student();

        String name = nameField.getText();

        //This is where I want to get the address value from
       //InputStudentAddressInfo.java and assign it to address

        // I tried creating a InputStudentAddressInfo object and calling the 
        // saveAddressButtonActionPerformed method from 
        //InputStudentAddressInfo but that doesn't work. 

  String address=InputStudentAddressInfo.saveAddressButtonActionPerformed(); 


}                                          



     // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton addAddress;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField nameField;
        private javax.swing.JButton saveButton;
     // End of variables declaration                   
 }
```

And here is the code for InputStudentAddressInfo

```
 package testswing;

 public class InputStudentAddressInfo extends javax.swing.JDialog {

     /**
      * Creates new form InputStudentAddressInfo
     */

     public InputStudentAddressInfo(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {

         super(parent, modal);

         initComponents();
     }



   private void saveAddressButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent 
   evt) {   

        // I need to assign the value entered in addressField to address and 
           then pass address to InputStudentInfo.java

           String address = addressField.getText();
       }                                                 

    public JTextField getAddressField() {

         return addressField;

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
       private javax.swing.JTextField addressField;
       private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
       private javax.swing.JButton saveAddressButton;
    // End of variables declaration                   
  }
```

As you can see from above I tried calling saveAddressButtonActionPerformed from InputStudentInfo in an attempt to get the value of address but that was clearly the wrong approach. So I need a method that returns address and can be called from InputStudentInfo. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Simply put, your `InputStudentAddressInfo` needs a "getter" which will return the value of the `addressField`

Comment: It might help to define your model first (in this case, model roughly = data).  Make a class called StudentAddress (or even just Address) and then have InputStudentAddressInfo collect all the data needed to build that class.  You will still need to have a "getter" as mentioned above to return a new copy of the StudentAddress class.

Comment: Would the getter be for addressField ( a JTextField) or address which is a String?

Comment: Definitely not JTextField, which should stay encapsulated.  I'd (again) use a class; combining different data into a string is considered poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is, your dialog needs to provide a "getter" method which returns the current value of the address field, something like...

```
public class InputStudentAddressInfo extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    //...
    public String getAddress() {
        return addressField.getText();
    }
    //...
}
```

for example.

The hard part is knowing when it's save to get the value.  You need to know if the user closed the dialog by pressing the save button or by closing the window via the title bar's close button.

To this end, you can maintain some kind of flag which can be inspected after the dialog is closed to make determinations about how the dialog might have been closed

```
public class InputStudentAddressInfo extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public enum State {
        SAVE, CANCEL
    }

    private State state;

    /**
     * Creates new form InputStudentAddressInfo
     */
    private InputStudentAddressInfo(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {

        super(parent, modal);
        state = State.CANCEL;
        initComponents();
    }

    private void saveAddressButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        state = State.SAVE;
        dispose();
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    //...
}
```

And because I'm overly lazy, I might add a `static` helper method...

```
public class InputStudentAddressInfo extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public static String show(java.awt.Frame parent) {
        InputStudentAddressInfo dialog = new InputStudentAddressInfo(parent, true);
        return dialog.getState() == State.SAVE ? dialog.getAddress() : null;
    }

    //...
}
```

This makes it easier to call the dialog and manage the output.  If the result is `null`, then the dialog was dismissed by the user, otherwise the value they entered is returned...

```
String address = InputStudentAddressInfo.show(parent);
if (address != null) {
    // You know have the address value
}
```

Of course, you could change it so that the `show` method returned both the state and value wrapped in another object, if the state was important to the caller, but this is just a simple example

Comment: Thanks I tried implemented this but I keep getting the error message "parent is not public in component; cannot be accessed from outside package" when I type String address = InputStudentAddressInfo.show(parent); on InputStudentInfo

Comment: Yeah, you need to pass in a reference to the parent frame, which I didn't include in the example, because I didn't demonstrate one. If you're calling it from `InputStudentInfo` you could probably simply use `this` as the parent reference

Comment: Sorry to ask a stupid question...I spent the last few hours trying to figure out what you meant but nothing seems to work...should I pass in a reference to the parent in the constructor on InputStudentInfo? this.parent = parent;

Comment: You can pass a reference of any object which deselects from `java.awt.Frame`, based on your problem description and available can, if you're trying to show the `InputStudentAddressInfo` dialog from within the `InputStudentInfo` class, you can use `this`, for example, `String address = InputStudentAddressInfo.show(this);`